# How to catch excel data refresh exception using python

Tags: python, excel, powerquery, pywin32

I have a python script that refreshes an entire excel workbook.
Its a standard win32 code like this...

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
excel.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()        
excel.DisplayAlerts = True
excel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
wb.Save()
```

I have added an error in the datasource so when i manually refresh the data, I see a pop-up with the error.
But with python script, the refresh completes successfully.
Is there a way to catch any exception thrown while refreshing using python?

I tried adding

```
excel.Visible = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = True
```

So i do see the excel opening and the query running but no error pop-up.